# Is it possible to burn a customized windows installation?

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation

I frequently run into the issue that I need to perform fresh installations of Windows, mostly Windows 7, but it's kinda tedious to also install some "common software" every time I install the OS. By "common software" I mean programs that I need to install on every computer that I install Windows on, like office suites, graphic design software, media players, typographic files, desktop tweaks, etc.

I've seen that at some places, custom Windows images are offered with some tweaks included (even already activated).

Is there a way that I can burn a "snapshot" of an already existing installation to a disc so that I can install it on another computer and that this new installation already has the aforementioned software installed in it (as it is in the original installation)?

Thanks!

Comment: Certainly this is done by new system manufacturers, and by the shops that set up systems for large companies.  My recollection is that it's done via a disk image (since the systems being installed are identical), but I've never done it and never paid attention to the details.  (But I'm guessing the above links go into this.)

Comment: Well there are two ways to do it: **(1)** disk images where you install Windows, install programs, clone the drive, and copy the image to the other systems; and **(2)** custom installations where you modify the Windows installation files so that when you install Windows, customization like settings and programs are automatically installed as well. It’s not clear which Gerard wants, but both have been asked and answered here, so see the above questions for advice.

Comment: Google "slipstreaming".

Answer (score 0):

Try [RTSe7enLite](http://www.rt7lite.com/).

Quote from their website:

> RT Se7en Lite is developed by Rockers Team to customize windows 7 operating system and to make it lite. You can add wallpapers, Icons, themes, integrate updates, drivers, language packs, applications, remove components, enable or disable features, unattended installation settings, bootable ISO and USB creator , etc. It will be very easy to operate and changing the style of your windows 7 operating system.

You can also install 3rd party programs, but they have to have a "silent" install option.

Edit: this is just for Windows 7. [Here](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/operating-systems/10-tools-for-creating-custom-windows-installation-discs-679477) is a list of other tools that include options for Vista and XP.